# Column Formatting

Tags: support, markdown

How can I use column Formatting on Stackoverflow.
I have tried the stackoverflow help but could not found anything related.
For example:

I have this data in column style.

```
Name      Address       City       Country  
John      street 26     Paris      France  
Darin     blck 2        Dubai      UAE
```

and so on.

Comment: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html